# Are the grpc generated stubs thread safe?

Tags: go, grpc

I am taking a look at the tutorials of grpc
https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go.html

The grpc unary call looks something like this

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(*serverAddr)
if err != nil {
    ...
}
defer conn.Close()
client := pb.NewRouteGuideClient(conn)
feature, err := client.GetFeature(context.Background(), &pb.Point{409146138, -746188906})
if err != nil {
        ...
}
```

I wanted to know if I call

```
   client.GetFeature
```

from multiple threads, is it thread safe?

Comment: It depends how you implement your server interface, you have to do it yourself, grpc will not generate implementation for you

Comment: @Vardius I meant at the client side

Answer (score 6):

Looking into this [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/85) you can learn that:

> [@rubenv](https://github.com/rubenv) asks:
>
> Can I use a client from different threads in parallel?
>
> [@iamqizhao](https://github.com/iamqizhao) replies:
>
> On client, if you want to perform multiple rpc in parallel, you should
>   spawn multiple goroutines to do that since the rpc is
>   synchronous/blocking

the answer is yes, however, a stream can't be shared ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/aI6L6M4fzQ0)).

> @trevorgray, these kinds of concurrency topics **are apparently still
>   not documented**, per [#682](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/682).